Slow git operation because of git LFS
The git operations in my local machine seem extremely slow because of git lfs. Operations like the git checkout branch or git commit take a long time.
time gco SAP-1205
Updating files: 100% (8288/8288), done.
Switched to branch 'SAP-1205'
git checkout SAP-1205  4.67s user 13.59s system 54% cpu 33.246 total

This happened because, during one of my project setups, I ran git lfs install, adding the following hooks that were extremely slowing down git operations.

pre-push
post-checkout
post-commit
post-merge

To fix this you can go do
git lfs uninstall

